# Translation of formula to PHP gives incorrect output

Tags: php, formula

I have the following formula

```
-32.16874499 = (0-0.02*1000)*(1+0.02)^24
```

When I create this formula in PHP it an echo of the paramters looks like:

```
(0-0.02*1000)*(1+0.02),24
```

This is just an echo of the PHP code:

```
$goalMonthly = pow((($J-$mIntrest*$T)*(1+$mIntrest)),$months);
```

`$goalMonthly` hold the value:  `26.985.099.156.891.700.138.339.884.597.248`

I would expect a value like `-32.16`

Comment: Link to the actual formula you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to how your formula is written it looks like you should have it like:

```
   $goalMonthly = ($J-$mIntrest*$T) * 
      pow((1+$mIntrest),$months);
```

Answer (score 2):

You were using pow on the whole expression.

It should be:

```
$goalMonthly = ($J-$mIntrest*$T)*pow((1+$mIntrest),$months);
```